# 18.04 Per Monitor HiDPI Scaling?

Tags: 18.04, hdpi

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my rMBP (2800x1800).  I need the scaling on the built-in monitor to be 2x, but I also have a 1080p monitor that needs to be set to 1x.  Currently I have to choose one or the other.

Is it possible to have it scale per monitor?

Comment: I checked, and although the dialog suggests that it could be set per monitor, indeed the setting applies to any monitor. This was on Xorg. If you are also on xorg, the default for Ubuntu 18.04, then try switching to Wayland. Chances are that it will work independently for each monitor on Wayland. You can switch between Xorg and Wayland anytime by selecting the appropriate session during log-in (click the cog icon before entering your password)